# GraphQL with AWS Amplify - how to enable sorting on query

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I've recently started looking into AWS Amplify.
I have managed to setup an API using GraphQl.
Basically, during the API creation, Amplify ask you a few questions about the API and guides you through its creation.
At some point, you are requested to create a schema. The schema I selected is as follows:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String
}

type Highscore @model {
  points: Int!,
  id: ID!
  ownerId: ID!,
  numRounds: Int,
  date: String, 
}
```

with this schema, Amplify is able to generate code that allows me to do things such as:

- mutate users and highscores
- query all Users
- query all Highscores

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

I've looked into the @key directive (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#key) but updating the schema to include

```
type Highscore @model @key((fields: ["points"] {
...
}
```

did not produce the expected result.

unfortunately, the code generated by Amplify using this schema **does not allow sorting of the query**.

**I would like to be able to query all Highscores, and sort it according to the number of points.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was raised and has been responded in the GitHub Amplify CLI repo.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2307

Comment: please put the solution here

Comment: why? That link is public, so everyone can navigate to it and see the solution, as well as the discussion around it, which is relevant for this case.