# Sorting results in AWS Amplify GraphQL without filtering

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

Provided a very simple model in `graphql.schema`, how would I perform a simple sort query?

```
type Todo @model
  id: ID!
  text: String!
}
```

Which generates the following in `queries.js`.

```
export const listTodos = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListTodos(
    $filter: ModelTodoFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listTodos(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        text
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

I have found multiple sources pointing me in the direction of the `@key` [directive](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#how-to-use-key). This similar question addresses that approach ([GraphQL with AWS Amplify - how to enable sorting on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954689/graphql-with-aws-amplify-how-to-enable-sorting-on-query)).

While that may seem promising and successfully generates new queries I can use, all the approaches I have tried require that I filter the data before sorting it. All I want to do is sort my todo results on a given column name, with a given sort direction (ASC/DESC).

This is how I would perform a simple (unsorted) query:
`const todos = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTodos));`

I would be looking to do something along the lines of:
`const todos = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTodos, {sortField: "text", sortDirection: "ASC"} ))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring `@searchable` incurs pointless extra server cost if all you need is straight forward sorting. It spins up an EBS and an OpenSearch that will be about $20 a month minumum.

Instead you need to use the `@index` directive.

As per the documentation here: https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-graphql/query-with-sorting/q/platform/js/

In your model, add the `@index` directive to one of the fields with a few parameters:

```
type Todo @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  type: String! @index(name: "todosByDate", queryField: "todosByDate", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  createdAt: String!
}
```

By declaring the `queryField` and the `sortKeyField` you will now have a new query available to once you push your amplify config:

```
query todosByDate {
  todosByDate(
    type: "Todo"
    sortDirection: ASC
  ) {
    items {
      id
      title
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
```

The field you declare this directive on can not be empty (notice the ! after the field name)

This is a much better way of doing it as opposed to `@searchable`, which is massively overkill.

Comment: To be fair, when the answer was given back in 2020, I think @index was not an option. This is definitely a better and more updated approach.

Answer (score 7):

Decorate your model with the `@searchable` directive, like so:

```
type Todo @model @searchable
{
  id: ID!
  text: String!
}
```

After that, you can query your data with sorting capabilities like below:

```
import { searchToDos } from '../graphql/queries';
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';

const toDoData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(searchToDos, {
  sort: {
    direction: 'asc',
    field: 'text'
  }
}));
console.log(toDoData.data.searchToDos.items);
```

For more information, see

- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1851#issuecomment-545245633
- https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/directives#searchable

Comment: Doesn't that require an additional dependency to AWS Elasticsearch (and additional server costs?)

Comment: Yes, this was the only approach (without filtering) I can find at the time of writing. Using AWS Elasticsearch might be worth it if you consider the flexibility & performance ElasticSearch offers over normal DB search queries.

Check out this article:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/combining-dynamodb-and-amazon-elasticsearch-with-lambda/

Comment: The other option is you can do client-side sorting, but that'd only work efficiently for small datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted MTran's answer because it feels to me it is the nearest thing to an actual solution, but I've also decided to actually opt for a workaround. This way, I avoid adding a dependency to ElasticSearch.

I ended up adding a field to my schema and every single entry has the same value for that field. That way, I can filter by that value and still have the entire table of values, that I can then sort against.

Comment: ahem...what? It's not clear at all